# Running a bash command with multiple lines of input via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos

I am trying to LDAP directory via ForgeRock's OpenDJ, I am sending most of the commands via ssh and it works, however I am stuck at one command which requires input in different line. Here is how it works, if I type it in shell:

```
ldapmodify -h server.example.com -p 1389 -w '1234' -D "cn=Directory\ Manager" -a 
dn:ou=test1,dc=example,dc=com 
objectclass:top 
objectclass:organizationalUnit
ou:test1
```

Note that there are four lines of input and the command concludes after getting one extra line of blank input (carriage-return). The command's input are dynamic and based on the variables. How can I send this multi-line command via ssh?

Here is how I am sending other commands:

```
SEND_REMOTE_CMD='opendj/bin/dsconfig create-backend 
--backend-name eg1 
--set base-dn:dc=eg1,dc=com
--set enabled:true
--type local-db
--hostname server.example.com
--port 5444
--trustAll
--bindPassword '1234'
--no-prompt
--bindDN "cn=Directory\ Manager"'

ssh user@server.example.com $SEND_REMOTE_CMD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To script a command and send it multiple lines of input you can use a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

```
ldapmodify -h server.example.com -p 1389 -w '1234' -D "cn=Directory\ Manager" -a <<INPUT
dn:ou=test1,dc=example,dc=com 
objectclass:top 
objectclass:organizationalUnit
ou:test1
INPUT
```

To do it over SSH, do the same thing, but add the ssh command in front.

```
ssh user@host.name ldapmodify -h server.example.com -p 1389 -w '1234' -D "cn=Directory\ Manager" -a <<INPUT
dn:ou=test1,dc=example,dc=com 
objectclass:top 
objectclass:organizationalUnit
ou:test1
INPUT
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass variables in Here Documents? Or if I can pre-compose a string and pass it into here documents?

Comment: Yes, you can use variables in here documents. Try it!